# Unable to access the class inside dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, class, dynamic

I've created a table using js. I've given class names for few cells. I want to access these cells later on and remove the class name. But I'm unable to do it. This is how I create the table dynamically:

```
for (var j = 0; j < TotalNumOfPlayers; j++) 
{
  // Create a <td> element and a text node, make the text
  // node the contents of the <td>, and put the <td> at
  // the end of the table row
  var cell = document.createElement("td");
  if (header)
  {
  var cellText = document.createTextNode(nameOfPlayers[j]);
  }
  else
  {
  var cellText = document.createTextNode(oldScore[j]);      
  cell.setAttribute("class", "lastrow");
  }
  cell.appendChild(cellText);
  row.appendChild(cell);  
}
```

Here is how I tried to access the cells and remove the classes:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".lastrow").classList.remove("lastrow");
```

It throws the following error:

> Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
>       at :1:48

I vaguely understand that it is looking at the parent level and sees no class attached but it should be looking inside the td. Did I get it right? If yes, how should I accomplish this?

Comment: Hi *querySelectorAll* returns an array you must put the index with that after that you selection code look like querySelectorAll(‘.lastrow’)[0]

Comment: instead `cell.setAttribute("class", "lastrow");` better use `cell.classList.add('lastrow')`

Comment: Wow.. Thanks Muhammad. That solved it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip Antosha. I'll remember this going forward. This is just a sample code :)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove class from all elements in loop

```
let lastrows = document.querySelectorAll('.lastrow');
for (let i=lastrows.length;i--;){
    lastrows[i].classList.remove('lastrow');
}
```